# Displying a specific row of a clicked button in Angular 8

Tags: angular, events, button, click

Am working on an SPA built using Angular 8, On the view I have a table whereby I display all the data from the backend and loop through it using ngFor loop. This works fine. On the delete button, I have written a logic whereby when the user clicks on the button, it shows the user a message **Are you sure you want to delete** , when the user accepts, it deletes the row.

The problem is when the button is clicked all the rows open and show the message. I want only the message to **be shown on the button that was clicked and not all the buttons**.

**Show.component.html**

```
 <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Age (Years)</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of userData">
       <td>
            {{ user.name}}
       </td>
       <td>
            {{ user.age}}
       </td>
       <td>
            {{ user.gender}}
       </td>
       <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="edit(user.id)">Edit</button>
        <span *ngIf="confirmDelete">
          <span> Are you sure you want to delete ?</span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Yes </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirmDelete=false">No </button>
        </span>
        <button *ngIf="!confirmDelete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="confirmDelete=true">Delete</button>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Show.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/Services/shared.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {  SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.css']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {
  public userData : any[];
  public error = null;

  constructor(
    private Shared : SharedService,
    private Auth:AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private Notify:SnotifyService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Shared.checkAll$.subscribe(message => this.userData = message);
  }

  //delete user
  deleteUser(id:number){
    return this.Auth.delete(id).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `user` object in the `*ngFor` to show/hide the delete confirmation. Instead of declaring `confirmDelete`, you should use `user.confirmDelete` as follows:

```
<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Age (Years)</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of userData">
       <td>
            {{ user.name}}
       </td>
       <td>
            {{ user.age}}
       </td>
       <td>
            {{ user.gender}}
       </td>
       <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="edit(user.id)">Edit</button>
        <span *ngIf="user.confirmDelete">
          <span> Are you sure you want to delete ?</span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Yes </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="user.confirmDelete=false">No </button>
        </span>
        <button *ngIf="!user.confirmDelete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="user.confirmDelete=true">Delete</button>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

By this way, you can show only one row at a time.

Comment: Thanks, am a bit new to Angular,, kindly assist me on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897979/updating-angular-dom-immediately-after-editing-data-and-retrieving-from-the-data)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are having the confirmation message with a flag **confirmdelete** and it will be turned to True when you click on the Delete button outside your span. i.e

```
<button *ngIf="!confirmDelete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="confirmDelete=true">Delete</button>
```

Hence when the flag is turned to True, the confirmation message will be shown to all the rows. You can try doing to same functionality by changing the confirmation message to a **sweet alert component** and just have a single button for delete user in the template. You need to remove the below code from the HTML template convert the same into sweet alert in the controller.

```
<span *ngIf="confirmDelete">
          <span> Are you sure you want to delete ?</span>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Yes </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirmDelete=false">No </button>
        </span>
```

So you last  would look like:

```
 <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="edit(user.id)">Edit</button>

        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</button>
       </td>
```

So on click of that button, inside your component, place a sweet alert from where the user will confirm whether to delete or not.

Reference link for the sweet alert component: - https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2

Comment: Thanks,,your answer was helpful but it didnt achieve my objectives

Comment: What have you changed? Like what is still not achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the button outside the ngFor loop, when you place the button within the ngFor it gets repeatedly opened.

Comment: When I place it outside the ngFor loop there will be an issue cause I wont be able to capture the id of the specific user to delete

Answer (score 0):

Make confirmDelete an object, with keys as the users' ids, and boolean values.
then, in the template, check for (or set) confirmDelete[user.id]:

```
<span *ngIf="confirmDelete[user.id]">
  <span> Are you sure you want to delete ?</span>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Yes</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirmDelete[user.id] = false">
    No
  </button>
</span>
<button
  *ngIf="!confirmDelete[user.id]"
  class="btn btn-danger"
  (click)="confirmDelete[user.id] = true"
>
  Delete
</button>
```

and in the .ts:

```
let confirmDelete = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martin:
You should write a method which will be called on button click. This method will be in .ts file. Once you click the button pass the information with this method and assign and store this information to the callback variable and open the popup. Now on button action over the popup you simply call the callback.