# Updating Angular DOM immediately after editing data and retrieving from the database

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, crud

Am working on a Single page Application built using Angular 8 on the frontend and Laravel on the backend. It is a CRUD application, on the delete functionality, it is working well by deleting the user of the specific id on the database. After the user of the specific id is deleted, am fetching all the products from the database but I want to update the data on the U.I afresh with the new data (excluding the deleted resource).

Kindly assist?

**Show.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/Services/shared.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/Services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {  SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.css']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {
  public userData : any[];
  public error = null;

  constructor(
    private Shared : SharedService,
    private Auth:AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private Notify:SnotifyService
    ) { }

  //Update the data when the DOM loads
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Shared.checkAll$.subscribe(message => this.userData = message);
  }

  //Method called when the delete button is triggered from the html
  //Inside it we submit the data to the backend via a service and get
  //the response
  deleteUser(id:number){
    return this.Auth.delete(id).subscribe(
      data => this.handleDeleteResponse(data),
      error => this.handleDeleteError(error)
    );
  }

  //data below contains data from the backend after successful deletion
  handleDeleteResponse(data:any){
    this.Notify.success(`Successfully Deleted in our records`, {timeout:4000});
  }

  handleDeleteError(error:any){
    console.log(error);
  }

}
```

Comment: You could re-fetch the new data from the database and assign it to userData again, just like you did it in ngOnInit()

Comment: After successfully deletion, you need to update the variable which is binded with the ui. If the variable data changes UI will reflect with the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

In you’re  handleDeleteResponse  method, there is a data if the data is the userData `this.userData = data` or it’s simple delete the user id from the array in you’re Js in the subscription of your delete method.

Like:

```
this.userData = this.userData.filter(user => user.id !== idToDelete )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
Define a Subject in your service and subscribe to that subject in the service to receive the data. In the component, change the lifecycle hook to 'onChanges'. As soon as the data in the Subject is received/updated (with the deleted records) ngChanges shall reflect it in the DOM.

**Method 2:**
Track the records on the front-end in the form of list and when the service gives the response of delete as success then delete that very record in the list using ID or any other unique identifier. In this case you need not to populate all the records again.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    ngOnChanges() {
    // code here
    }
    ngOnInit() {
     // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: ,, Thanks alot,, how can I use ngOnChanges in the typescript file

Comment: I have updated my answer. Also please view (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges)